# Python - replace all instances of comma between two XML tags

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all instances of commas within `<in:xref> and </in:xref>` and replace them with `<found>,</found>`. So, the following:

```
<in:xref>`CPR N52.20 [1A], CPR 52.10[1A], TAB 19`</in:xref>
```

should appear like this:

```
<in:xref>`CPR N52.20 [1A]`<found>,</found>` CPR 52.10[1A]`<found>,</found>` TAB 19`</in:xref>
```

but I don't seem to be getting anywhere?

Comment: Can you better format the data and the expected output using the code tags and add a few lines so that the example is a little clearer? It helps to see if it appears on one or multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks Nasir, didn't realise it looked so terrible first time around. Much better now

Comment: No problem. Does each line begin with `<in:xref>` and end with `</in:xref>`? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: To be more clear, do all the lines that contain those strings begin with `<in:xref>` and end with `</in:xref>`?

Comment: I don't think so its valid XML tag. <in:xref>

Comment: Hi Nasir, no, the in:xref is a child element and can appear in the middle of other markup. I'm on Windows 10

Comment: I think the inclusion of `:` in an element is not a great idea. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: Are opening and closing tags to be expected on the same line or not? Can there be more then one of these elements on a single line? This information impacts how complex/robust the solution needs to be.

Comment: The opening and closing tag always appear on the same line and there should only be one set of tags per line